# shade auto-smooth ceates holes in mesh

Tags: cycles-render-engine, shaders, geometry

when I shade my object auto smooth I get holes along the edges, shade smooth does not create this problem but an edge-split with auto smooth does. The normals are facing the correct way and there is no double geometry. The issue only occurs in cycles, not in evee. Can anyone explain this to me?
[image: The Problem]

[image: Normals]

Comment: I cannot recreate this effect, and actually I cannot see a reason why a shading option like _Auto Smooth_ should make it look like there are gaps between faces. Are you sure there are no other modifiers etc. on the mesh which can create this effect? Especially since there is a difference between _Cycles_ and _Eevee_ I'm thinking of things like displacement in the shader which only works in _Cycles_ and could of course pull faces away from each other when the edges are split. Maybe you should upload your file here and edit it into your question: https://blend-exchange.com

Comment: Gordon is on point, now I see it - it's the displacement in the shader, which works only in Cycles.

Comment: Thank you for your comment! I didn't have any modifiers but when I read your comment I tried disabling the displacement in the texture setup and that fixed the problem. Now I'm still confused because how is that a thing?